# how to create this If statement correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create an if statement that only lets role_id 2,3,4 view all call_center data, otherwise i only want users with correct auth to view their own call center data in my dashboard. I have a start but could use some help getting it work correctly. Below is my current if statement I am trying to get work. I know it may be incorrect, if so a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
if($role_id['id'] == '2' || $role_id['id'] == '3' || $role_id['id'] == '4') {
            if ($user_id != Auth::user()->id)
            {
                $user_id != $call_center
            }
        }
```

Here is the whole function in my dashboardcontroller.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $role_id = User::UserRoleData()->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first();
        $call_center = Auth::user()->call_center;
        $call_center = ($call_center == null ? '' : $call_center);
        $call_center = !empty($input['call_center']) ? $input['call_center'] : $call_center;
        $month = !empty($input['month']) ? $input['month'] : 'twentyfour';
        $sellertype = !empty($input['sellertype']) ? $input['sellertype'] : 'seller';
        $companies = Company::DistinctCompanies()->orderby('name')->get();
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now -24 months'));

        if($role_id['id'] == '2' || $role_id['id'] == '3' || $role_id['id'] == '4') {
            if ($user_id != Auth::user()->id)
            {

            }
        }
        // } else {
        //     $user_id->$call_center = Auth::user()->call_center;
        // }


        $pending = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Pending')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $active = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Active')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $cancelled_contracts = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Cancelled')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $late_contracts = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Late')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $back_out_contracts = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Back Out')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $pending_late = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Pending Late')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $pending_cancellation = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Awaiting Cancellation')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        if($sellertype == 'dealership')
        {
        $pending->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $active->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $cancelled_contracts->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $late_contracts->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $back_out_contracts->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $pending_late->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $pending_cancellation->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        }

        if($month == 'twentyfour' || $month != 'all')
        {
            $pending->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $active->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $cancelled_contracts->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $late_contracts->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $back_out_contracts->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $pending_late->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $pending_cancellation->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
        }
        if($call_center == '52')
        {
            $asi_contracts = array('26', '35', '4', '42', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51');
            $pending
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $active
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $cancelled_contracts
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $late_contracts
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $back_out_contracts
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $pending_late
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $pending_cancellation
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

        }

        if($role_id['id'] == '5' || $role_id['id'] == '6' || $role_id['id'] == '7' || $role_id['id'] == '8' || $role_id['id'] == '9' || $role_id['id'] == '10')
        {
            {
                $pending->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $active->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $cancelled_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $late_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $back_out_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $pending_late->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $pending_cancellation->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($role_id['id'] == '2' && !empty($input['call_center']))
            {
                $call_center = $input['call_center'];
                {
                    $pending->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $active->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $cancelled_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $late_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $back_out_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $pending_late->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $pending_cancellation->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                }
            }
        }


        $pending = $pending->get()->first();
        $active = $active->get()->first();
        $cancelled_contracts = $cancelled_contracts->get()->first();
        $late_contracts = $late_contracts->get()->first();
        $back_out_contracts = $back_out_contracts->get()->first();
        $pending_late = $pending_late->get()->first();
        $pending_cancellation = $pending_cancellation->get()->first();


        View::share('active_nav', 'Dashboard');
        return view('dash.dash')
            ->with('pending_contracts', number_format($pending->total))
            ->with('month', $month)
            ->with('sellertype', $sellertype)
            ->with('active', number_format($active->total))
            ->with('companies', $companies)
            ->with('call_center', $call_center)
            ->with('year', date("Y"))
            ->with('cancelled_contracts', number_format($cancelled_contracts->total))
            ->with('late_contracts', number_format($late_contracts->total))
            ->with('back_out_contracts', number_format($back_out_contracts->total))
            ->with('pending_late', number_format($pending_late->total))
            ->with('pending_cancellation', number_format($pending_cancellation->total));

    }
```

Comment: You've defined "$user_id = Auth::user()->id;" so your "if($user_id != Auth::user()->id)" statement will always be false. (btw, just a tip, you can write Auth::user()->id shorter as Auth::id() ). Also, what are you trying to do with "$user_id != $call_center" ?

Comment: If the user has the right permissions and is authorized, they can look at all call_centers. If the user only has permission to look at a certain call_center (they are assigned to) then they aren't permitted to look at different call_centers.  @MrEvers

Comment: I know, but your code is a bit peculiar. If UserRoleData() is a function of the user model, why not write it to check the current user object, instead of having to check the id separately? $role_id is an object, but you try to use it as an array. $user_id != $call_center doesn't actually change anything, it just compares. $user_id is variable, you can't do $user_id->$call_center

Comment: This is my function in the user model, what would you reccomend adding? 
   ```public function scopeUserRoleData($query)
    {
        $roletitle = $query->leftjoin('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->leftjoin('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')->select('roles.role_title', 'roles.id');

         return $roletitle;

    }```

Comment: If I understand correctly, each user can have several roles, and the pivot table is role_user? In that case you can just define a many-to-many relationship, as explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many to get your roles

Comment: This may likely be a situation that I would create a guard or a middleware. Then you could use different middleware for different routes. Therefore the users that should hit that method on your dashboard controller are admins. If they are not return an exception and handle they way you want so your end users who get it understand they don&amp;#39;t have the necessary authentication or are forbidden from seeing this content.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes